# What is wrong with this amateur KeyFactory and Encrypt code

Tags: java, encryption

I dont understand what i do wrong, This code is three steps

- Create public and private keys (save to disk)
- encrypt the text "hello hello"
- decrypt the text "hello hello"

but the output from this code is

[B@7455d93d (after encrypt)
[B@3bc0f2e5 (after decrypt)

im doing some really amateur error but cannot figure it out

.

```
public class KeyPairsGenerator {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        KeyPairsGenerator testClass = new KeyPairsGenerator();
        testClass.GenerateKeyPair();
        testClass.testEncryptDecrypt();
    }

    public void testEncryptDecrypt(){

        ObjectInputStream oinPublic = null;
        ObjectInputStream oinPrivate = null;
        try {

            //****************
            //ENCRYPT
            oinPublic = new ObjectInputStream
            (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("public.key")));
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oinPublic.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oinPublic.readObject();
            RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal("hello hello".getBytes());

            System.out.println(cipherData.toString());

            //****************
            //DECRYPT
            oinPrivate = new ObjectInputStream
            (new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("private.key")));
            BigInteger m1 = (BigInteger) oinPrivate.readObject();
            BigInteger e1 = (BigInteger) oinPrivate.readObject();
            RSAPrivateKeySpec keySpecPrivate = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(m1, e1);
            KeyFactory fact1 = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privKey = fact1.generatePrivate(keySpecPrivate);

            Cipher cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
            byte[] cipherData1 = cipher1.doFinal(cipherData);

            System.out.println(cipherData1.toString()); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Spurious serialization error", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                oinPrivate.close();
                oinPublic.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void GenerateKeyPair()
    {       
        try{
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            kpg.initialize(2048);
            KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();

            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec pub = fact.getKeySpec(
                    kp.getPublic(),RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = fact.getKeySpec
            (kp.getPrivate(),RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

            saveToFile("public.key", pub.getModulus(),pub.getPublicExponent());
        saveToFile("private.key", priv.getModulus(),priv.getPrivateExponent());
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void saveToFile(String fileName,BigInteger mod, 
            BigInteger exp) throws Exception {

        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream
        (new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName)));
        try {
            oout.writeObject(mod);
            oout.writeObject(exp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("error", e);
        } finally {
            oout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"hello hello".getBytes()` You should specify a character encoding here otherwise the two parties might use something incompatible.

Comment: good comment yea that would have made problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cipherData1.toString()` doesn't do what you think it does.

You probably want `new String(cipherData1)`.

Comment: except that this is binary data. Maybe something like Base64 first.

Comment: @Oli that's it.. thanks so much. it's working with the  new String(cipherData1). Will try to send some passwords over the Internet now

Comment: @Thilo: The decrypted data ought to be the same as the original.

Comment: Okay... I was just looking at the variable name, which sounded like it was ciphertext...

Comment: Binary data gets treated correctly by the new String() command.

Comment: @Thilo: Goncalo is wrong but you are also. You are being misled by the name of the array, `cipherData1`. It is actually plaintext, the result of decryption, and if you look elsewhere in the code you can see that it is the result from String.getBytes(). Thus it is correct to use it in the constructor for String. Though it is a bug to not explicitly specify the charset.

Comment: @GregS: `cipherData1` is clear text, but `cipherData` is not (and it is also turned into a string that way).

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Arrays.toString(byte[])` to display the byte array. `byte[].toString()` returns the type of the array (`[B`) followed by its `hashCode`.

You could also use Base64 to encode your byte arrays as ASCII strings. Apache commons-codec has a free implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your cipherData and cipherData1 are coming in as a byte array, you need to turn these into a String, the .toString() that is available to the array class is the generic .toString() and it doesn't really return to you the byte Array in a String format, to do this you need to do `System.out.println(new String(cipherData))` and `System.out.println(new String(chiperData1))` which ends up being better than allocating it to a String in memory prior printing it.

EDIT:
On an added note, if you're thinking about doing a cross-platform communication with this, also state the encoding, ie: 
- `new String(cipherData, "UTF-8")` 
- `new String(cipherData, "ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: the private key will be used by any android device world width maybe. yea this is important

Comment: well if you are going to be doing a Server-client communication then I'd recommend dual encryption, an RSA encryption with the public key on the client side (android devices), which you then use to send the encryption key (for the second encryption method) that is generated by the device, this means you can have the private key pretty much safe on the server side and only the public key is available.
For a secondary encryption algorythm I'd recommend TEA or something similar.
I did something like this for a project that runs smoothly on old phones, so it should work rather well on Android.

Comment: Do you mean that both server and client should create key there own key pairs private/public keys. I dont understand fully. Now my server have the RSA private key and my client use the public key to send the login pass/user name to server. How can TEA make this safer?

Comment: if you keep RSA for a "login" connection, and in this primary connection you send the (TEA) key that the client generates each time the app is run, you end up permitting both client and server to decrypt TEA according to a session key.
TEA isn't safer than RSA, however if you use it in conjunction with RSA in the method I specified above it ends up making a more safe data transaction between client and server since the RSA private key is only known to the server, and the TEA key gets generated on each session.

Comment: thanks, i have limited base knowledge to comprehend this. I will start with the RSA and move from there.